# find: './proc/1/map_files': Permission denied

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, search, alpine-linux

I am inside a docker container build atop of the image `alpine:3.6` and I am trying to find if a directory exists. I get te error,

```
find: './proc/1/map_files': Permission denied
```

This is the commands I used for the search,

```
root@5f4776320924:/# ls
bin   docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  home   media  proc  sbin  tmp
boot  entrypoint.sh       lib    mnt    root  srv   usr
dev   etc             lib64  opt    run   sys   var
root@5f4776320924:/# find . -type d | grep "adminer"
find: './proc/1/map_files': Permission denied
```

If I try to use the `root` using `$ su -`, I only get inside the `root` folder and I wasn't able to perform the search.

What's the issue here? I think the searching command is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is correct (although a bit overcomplicated, using the `name` option of `find` instead of grepping would be better).

`find / -type d -name adminer`

`/proc` is a very special filesystem which contains information about running processes. Therefore, not everything is accessible (not even to root). The Linux Documentation Project has a good writeup:

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Comment: I have checked the page you mentioned, but, this is kind of over the edge. What do we need to do to find a directory in the `Linux` container?

Comment: The command is correct! If it doesn't return something, then the directory does not exist. You should use `find / -type d -name adminer` (and if you don't want to see the error messages, add `2>/dev/null`)

Comment: still, it would've been interesting to know why /proc/1/map_files/ is not readable by the "root" from a docker container. Saying that /proc is "very special" isn't very edifying -- I'm very special, too ;-)